# Logistic regression coefficient interpretation

Tags: logistic, categorical-data

There is one binary dependent variable (Winner/Loser) and there are three independent variables which are also categorical in nature:

- Age (Below 31, 31-40, 41-50, 51-60, 61 and above while retaining 61 and above as a reference category),
- Gender (Male, Female while retaining Female as the reference category), and
- Education (Literate, Below matric, Matric, Graduate, Postgraduate, Above postgraduate while retaining Above postgraduate as the reference category).

While interpreting the odds-ratio results **against the reference category**, it becomes difficult to understand the individual contribution of the variables involved in the equation.

Please advise what should I do for this problem.

Kind regards,

Stuti

Comment: I would start by not categorizing the age variable and including it as numeric instead. Categorizing it loses statistical power and makes interpretation unnecessarily complicated. As for the other variables, the levels of each categorical variable are treated as seperate variables. You can't really interpret each variable, only the levels.

Comment: How should I analyze the data in this case where there is one dependent variable (categorical) and several independent variables (categorical with different categories)?

Comment: Logistic regression. The normal approach is to use contrast coding where the estimates are with respect to a reference level. You could also look into lsmeans.